# Qt - вызов sync() для клaсса QSettings

Tags: qt

Можно ли управлять вызовом `sync()` для класса `QSettings`?

Comment: Что значит "управлять вызовом"? Метод `sync` публичный, его можно просто вызвать в случае необходимости

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но в описании метода sync() есть предупреждение

["Эта функция вызывается автоматически из деструктора QSettings и цикла событий через регулярные промежутки времени, поэтому вам обычно не нужно делать вызов самостоятельно"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#sync)

Comment: Мне-то как раз нужно как-то ЗАПРЕТИТЬ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИЙ вызов  sync(). Дело в том, что у меня на основе QSettings основано логирование курсирующих сообщений (через сокеты), и sync() заметно тормозит этот процесс.